# find: double wildcard

Tags: find, wildcards

I do

```
find path/to/folder -name *foo.sh
```

The utility lists the relevant files.

However, if I do

```
find path/to/folder -name *foo*
```

I receive an error:

```
find: paths must precede expression:
```

Why? What to do?

Comment: @pLumo, yes, writing `find path/to/folder -name '*foo*'`works.